# Parent name extraction based on child value in JSON object.

Tags: java, json, gson

I would like to extract the parent name based on a search either on the entire JSON object or on value based on it key.

Eg.

```
"PersonA": {
  "shortnames": [
    "Bravo"
    "Delta"
  ],
  "Name": "Person 123",
  "Age": "15",
  "Maritial Status": "Single",
  "Work Exxperience": "O",
  "ID": 291},
"PersonB": {
"shortnames": [
  "Alpha"
  "Tango"
],
"Name": "Person 234",
"Age": "60",
"Maritial Status": "Married",
"Work Exxperience": "2O",
"ID": 292}
```

What I would like to do is

a) [Free Search] Search for some variable `Bravo` within the JSON and if exists, return the parent node name as `PersonA`

b) [Key value based search] If I search for key-value pair `Work Experience = 20` then return Parent node as `PersonB`

I am using GSON library to parse JSON. Can GSON achieve this?. Are there any other libraries which can do this?

Comment: Gson can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JsonPath](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.4.0/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html).

refer to [README](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) on github for more information on how to use JsonPath.

Comment: No luck there either. Would tell me how can we construct such a query in jsonpath